# Sympy not able to calculate minimum of a cubic root with an interval set

Tags: python, sympy

So I was working on a project and I came across this error related to sympy:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Andres\OneDrive - Centre d'Estudis Monlau\z.ottro\final program try 1\testing area 2.py", line 4, in <module>
    Ymin = minimum(root(x,3), x, domain=Interval(-7,7))
  File "C:\Users\Andres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\calculus\util.py", line 837, in minimum       
    return function_range(f, symbol, domain).inf
  File "C:\Users\Andres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\calculus\util.py", line 220, in function_range    range_int += Interval(vals.inf, vals.sup, left_open, right_open)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\sets\sets.py", line 274, in inf
    return self._inf
  File "C:\Users\Andres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\sets\sets.py", line 1910, in _inf
    return Min(*self)
  File "C:\Users\Andres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\functions\elementary\miscellaneous.py", line 391, in __new__
    args = frozenset(cls._new_args_filter(args))
  File "C:\Users\Andres\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\functions\elementary\miscellaneous.py", line 564, in _new_args_filter
    raise ValueError("The argument '%s' is not comparable." % arg)
ValueError: The argument '(-7)**(1/3)' is not comparable.
```

I was able to isolate where happened and recreate the error with these lines:

```
from sympy import *
x = Symbol("x")

Ymin = minimum(root(x,3), x, domain=Interval(-7,7))
```

I'm not undrestanding why it's happening, as when is root(x,2) it doasn't have this problem. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: Is it possible to code `7**(1/3)`? As a last resort, since the root of the number represent a equilateral triangle in the [Gaussian plane](https://www.mathematics-online.org/inhalt/aussage/aussage378/), you can find all other roots using `x^(1/3) * (cos(2*pi/3) ± i*sin(2*pi/3))`.

Comment: The expression is not real throughout the domain (e.g. `root(-1, 3).evalf()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey i found an answer online posted by user6655984(stackoverflow) and i wanted to share it online:
expression  = root(Abs(x), 3)*sign(x)

Comment: So is it not possible to take the `root` of a negative number?

Comment: i think it doasn't like doing roots of negative numbers with odd index

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).